# How do I make a div appear after a couple of seconds after mouseover with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, mouseover, show-hide

An image should also appear to show the loading process. In mouseout, the div should disappear. My code:

```
$("a").mouseenter(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(3000).html("<img src='load.gif' />");
    $("#div"+link).slideDown(100);
    $("#flash").fadeOut();
});

$("a").mouseout(function() {
    $("#flash").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the jQuery's [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method:

It's basically like `setTimeout` but allows chaining.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("my-element").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).delay(2000).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the div+link part to slide down after a couple of seconds?  [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) is good for that.

```
$("a").mouseenter(function(){

        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#flash").show();
        $("#flash").fadeIn(3000).html("<img src='load.gif' />");

        setTimeout(function() {
           $("#div"+link).slideDown(100);
        }, 2000);

        $("#flash").fadeOut();
});
```

**UPDATE:** 
The problem with setTimeout is you can't cancel it once it's queued up.  Instead you can try `setInterval`, because it returns an id of the timer that you can call `clearInterval` on later.

```
var timerId = null;

$("a").mouseenter(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(3000).html("<img src='load.gif' />");

    timerId  = setInterval((function() {
                   clearInterval(timerId);
                   $("#div"+link).slideDown(100);
               }, 2000);

    $("#flash").fadeOut();
});

$("a").mouseout(function(){

    clearInterval(timerId);
    $("#flash").fadeOut(1000);

});
```

**It's important that you call `clearInterval`, so that the function call doesn't keep repeating.**

Comment: Thanks Kon, this works to an extend but i want the timeout to stop in  mouseout. Anyway you can help me in that.

Comment: What do you mean you want timeout to stop?

Comment: i dont want the $("#div"+link).slideDown(100); to happen